# pull to refresh in tableview from presenting modal in iOS 13 not working

Tags: ios, tableview, modalviewcontroller, ios13, uirefreshcontrol

I've used UIRefreshControl inside the tableview and it presented the view controller as automatically in ios 13. The tableview inside the same view controller is used.

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
```

The problem is that as soon as swipe refresh top the view controller it dismiss.
i have prevented the following code for dismiss but the view controller still does not refresh from top.

```
vc.isModalInPresentation = true
```

**How do I refresh the tableview without dismiss the view controller?**

Comment: Try presenting it full screen instead of automatic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If iOS version is 10 later，use tableView's RefreshControl, don't ues addSubview.

```
let refreshControl:UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl.init()

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
   tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
} else {
   tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

No matter isModalInPresentation is true or false.